# Well fluid stabilizer by A.C. Hartsell

Tags: us2739652

Where may I find information regarding the history of this tool from 1949 to 2014?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the history of a specific invention. We can only help you with details about an actual patent (as compared to being about the invention, for the most part), or the patent process. You might want to check out the [help/on-topic] for more information, or feel free to ask on [meta].